# Is it possible in recharts to set how big the interval should be between tics?

Tags: javascript, recharts

I am trying to customize number of xaxis tics in my bar chart. I like how recharts automatically has squeezed most of the data points before 50 but I would really like the tics to be more like 0,50,100,150,200,250.[image: Bar chart]

If I ad `type="number"` and `tics={[0,50,100,150,200,250]}` to XAxis I get the tics to work but with the problem that it is hard to "read" the chart since all data points are squeezed in the lower left corner.

```
<BarChart
      width={1000}
      height={300}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5,
      }}>
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="1 1" />
      <XAxis dataKey="name" domain={[0, 'dataMax']} />
      <YAxis type="number" tick={<CustomizedAxisTick />} allowDataOverflow />
      <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
      <Bar dataKey="logValue" fill="#8884d8" />
    </BarChart>
```

Comment: Which package are you using for the barchart?

Comment: recharts (http://recharts.org)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but you can use the interval property to preserve start and end, or set the pixel count.

http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/LineChartAxisInterval